# Why didn't Hank connect the locations the blue meth had been found with Gus?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

At the end of *Breaking Bad* season 2, Hank Schrader is showing a map to his crew.  It contains pins for the locations that the blue meth had been seen.  He noted that it was appearing all across the south west, but for New Mexico itself, and reasoned that Heisenberg had smartened up and wasn't supplying it in his home state any longer.

[image]

Later, he comes to suspect Gustavo Fring of his involvement and tries (unsuccessfully) to convince his work mate Steve Gomez and ASAC George Merkert, but there is no mention of the map, nor any comment that Los Pollos Hermanos has branches in each of those states.

Did he forget the map, or is there something I overlooked as to why he did not mention it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (two) episodes you are referring to are [**Problem Dog**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_Dog) and **[Hermanos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermanos_%28Breaking_Bad%29)** - episodes 7 and 8 of Season 4.

In the former, Hank reveals his doubts to his colleagues and reveals that a fingerprint from Gus Frings was found at Gale's apartment.

This leads them to call him in for questioning in the following episode. Gus reveals he had visited Gale to congratulate him on a scholarship. When pressed on why he has no records from his time in Chile, he reasons that he left during the dictatorship of Pinochet and record keeping was awful.

These answers appear to appease all the other lawmen present (except Hank) and Gus is released.

Following this, he begins to investigate Gus' businesses (with Walt) to try and find some sort of connection.

Now, as to *your question* regarding the map - I think the most likely reason is because it's far too *tenuous* a connection. Gus Frings is a respected business man in charge of a chain operating across the entire South West. Whilst Hank could have mentioned it, it seems unlikely his colleagues would accept it. He happens to have restaurants around the cities/districts that the drugs were found in? Well, so do a ton of other business men. What makes Frings special? The fingerprint, obviously - except Hank's colleagues have now decided that was totally innocent.

So to proceed, Hank needed something else. That, in my opinion, is why he never mentioned the map. It wouldn't have provided any sort of definitive proof.

Comment: Further to your point of him being a respected businessman, remember that Gus was known to cater events for the police in Albuquerque, which definitely didn't help Hank's case against Gus. We even see him offer to help when Hank is injured by the two brothers from the cartel. Hank is a sharp cop, but Gus knows how to play the game. `You keep your friends close, and your enemies closer.`